# Complex Weierstrass M-test question.

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Use the Weierstrass M-test to show $\forall\epsilon>0,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nn^{-z}$ converges uniformly if $Re(z)>=1+\epsilon$, where $a_{n}$ is bounded.

This is what I've done:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nn^{-z}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_ne^{-zLog(n)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_ne^{-(Re(z)+iIm(z))Log(n)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_ne^{-(Re(z)+iIm(z))Log(n)}$$

I know this isn't much, but I have no idea how to handle this problem. We know $|a_{n}|<=C$ for some constant C since it is bounded. My only other idea is to say z <= R for some half disk $D=\{z:|z-c|<R\}$ for some $c > 1$. But then the issue comes with how do I get absolute values in the exponent $z$ of $\frac{1}{n^z}$?

Comment: Do you know what the modulus of $n^{-z}$ is? Can you write $\lvert n^{-z}\rvert$ as an expression in $n$, $\operatorname{Re} z$ and $\operatorname{Im} z$ not involving $\lvert\,\cdot\,\rvert$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z=a+ib$ with by hypothesis $a\ge1+\epsilon$ then we have
$$\left|\frac {a_n}{n^z}\right|=\left|\frac {a_n}{n^{a}}\right|\times \left|\frac {1}{n^{ib}}\right|\le\frac{M}{n^a}$$
where $M$ is an upper bound of $(a_n)$
and since the series $\sum_n \frac1{n^a}$ is a Riemann converget series then by the Weierstrass M-test the given series is convergent on the domain
$$\{z\in\Bbb C\quad |\quad \operatorname{Re} z>1\}$$

Comment: I think my issue was a basic one: Since $n^{a+ib}=n^{a}(cos(blna)+isin(blna)), |n^{a+ib}|=n^{a}, so |n^{ib}|=1$, correct? It's always random basic topics like this that get me...

Comment: Yes you're correct now.